# How do I install indicator-keylock?

Tags: indicator

Does someone know if there is a caps lock indicator for 11.10.  I am used to using "indicator-keylock" in 11.04.  I have added the repository but appears is not supported in 11.10.

Package indicator-keylock is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Answer (score 9):

indicator-keylock is in Ubuntu universe starting from 14.10.

For 10.04 to 12.04, you can use this PPA:

[https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock/+packages [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock/+packages)

There is also a PPA with daily builds containing packages for 12.10

[https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock-daily/+packages [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock-daily/+packages)

To install it just do

[ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```

or to install the daily build version (currently needed for Ubuntu 12.10 and later):

[ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock-daily [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock-daily) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock-daily && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```

Comment: Hello, how to install this on the newly official Ubuntu Unity flavour ? Thanks